# Meaning of "give me chills"

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-usage, phrases

Its winter in region these days, a friend uploaded a picture of water of summer from some other region. And that photo gave me goose bumps and i felt a sudden rush of cold in my body, so if i say "this photo gave me chills, would that be correct? Like it is said here? https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111123001539AAcqr4k
Are there any other phrase, words that could replace this one?

Comment: Usually when something gives someone chills it has either excited them to an extreme level or it has frightened them.  If that was your experience, then yes, the phrase is appropriate.

Comment: I just learned a new word: "frissons", which I think might be used as a substitute for "chills". I saw it in this sentence: "I regularly experience frissons when listening to an interesting piece [of music]". This was written by an Italian, so I'm not sure how it looks to a native English speaker (I'm not one).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "this photo gave me chills" is perfectly fine. "This photo gave me goosebumps" works too. Both phrases would be immediately understood by a native speaker.

**Edit**: As @WhatRoughBeast pointed out, this phrase can also be used to mean "it frightened me" or "it made me very uneasy".

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to include the fact that "gave me chills" or "gave me goosebumps" can also mean "it made me very uneasy" or "it frightened me". As in "The expression on his face gave me chills."

Comment: Also used (in AmE, at least):  _That photo gave me shivers._

Comment: @Adam: I'm a native speaker, and I can't say I've ever heard that variant. Maybe it's a regional thing?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Do you mean using "shivers" without an article, or using shivers at all?  nGrams shows quite a bit of use of _the shivers,_ although _chills_ is gaining in recent years: http://bit.ly/Shivills

Comment: @Adam Interesting. I'm not used to hearing either one. "Gave me shivers down my spine" is more familiar.

Comment: @NateBarbettini, probably "sent shivers down my spine", not "gave"...